# NGINX 404 when requesting non root location

Tags: php, nginx, server, http-status-code-404, config

I have this basic conf file:

```
server {

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/default/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass my-php:9000; 
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        internal;

        fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT $server_port;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
      return 404;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
         deny  all;
    }
}
```

located in the Nginx docker conteainer:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

it works well if I request website

127.0.0.1:8080

but fails with 404 if I want to access from a browser a file:
127.0.0.1:8080/check.php

even the file exists in the public dir and if I rename it to `index.php` it loads wihtout any problem by requesting `127.0.0.1:8080` but what needs to be changed in nginx conf so the `check.php` file would be available by `127.0.0.1:8080/check.php`?

Issue2:
I can request `127.0.0.1:8080` with 200 OK and BODY as expected but I get:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/index.php 404 Not Found
http://127.0.0.1:8080/check.php 404 Not Found
```

and if I turn off this block:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

i get access.log `"GET / HTTP/1.1" 403`
and request-response

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/ 403 Forbidden
```

but this matching seems to work:

```
location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) { ... }
```

for php because if I make fastcgi_pass invalid

```
fastcgi_pass wrong-containername:9000;
```

i get errors instead of 200 OK.

1.How to make a pattern for php-fpm location that will work with

```
http(s)://127.0.0.1:8080/
http(s)://127.0.0.1:8080/index.php
http(s)://127.0.0.1:8080/check.php
```

2.And additional that handles all other requests with php-fpm to dirs where could be index.php, or check.php or whatever.php

```
http(s)://127.0.0.1:8080/*
```

Answer (score 0):

You config allows for execution of only the `index.php`. It is a secure config, so I recommend keeping it in place with adjustment to list any additional scripts, e.g. change:

```
location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
```

to

```
location ~ ^/(index|check)\.php(/|$) {
```

Will allow executing only `/index.php` and `/check.php`.

Comment: I tired your answer but it did not work, That's probably because I get: `http://127.0.0.1:8080/index.php 404 Not Found` for `index.php` so probably there is another problem not related to `check.php` See edit of my question.